# Why does java.lang.Integer not contain a .charValue()?

Tags: java, jvm, primitive-types

All types of primitives can be retrieved from `java.lang.Integer` except `char`. Every primitive holds a number expression, so why does java not allow `Integer.charValue()`? Is `char` not a number? I also noticed that `java.lang.Character` doesn't extend `java.lang.Number`.

Comment: What would the `charValue` of 2 000 000 000 be?

Comment: @stunbar Your point makes no sense as there is `Integer.byteValue()`

Comment: That makes sense.  A byte is a number and it would just take the low 8 bits.  A Character is represented by least 16 bits but maybe more.  This is dependent on the character set.  So what would `charValue` return?  16 bits?  32 bits?  Or 8 bit ASCII?  It will vary

Comment: The char primitive has a max value of 65,535, so it should return 16 bits (unsigned). Even in bytecode chars and booleans are handled as ints, so I don't really understand why there is no `charValue` or `booleanValue`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, char is not a number. Char is UTF encoding. 
Unicode is a 16-bit character encoding system. The lowest value is **\u0000** and the highest value is **\uFFFF**.
Also char is unsigned type.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. In bytecode chars are represented as ints, so why is java.lang.Character not a java.lang.Number?

Comment: @GraxCode you could say the same about `Boolean`. Still, there are semantic differences between `boolean`, `char`, and `int`.